# When constructor is called and when operator function

Tags: c++, constructor, operator-keyword, copy-constructor

```
class apple
{
  public :
    operator orange () const { cout << "operator"; }
} ;
class orange
{
  public :
    orange (apple &x ){cout <<"constructor";}
};
void f(orange o)
{
  cout <<"function can accept only oranges ";
}
int main()
{
  apple a;
  f(a);
}
```

Output:
Compiler Error

Why does this code gives compiler error on g++ compiler? Why isn't the constructor for orange called when function f is called?

Comment: Please add the error message to your question.

Comment: You can have operator+, operator-, operator= and many others... but not an "operator orange".

Comment: `class orange` is undefined when used in `class apple` definition.

Comment: @Imp this is a conversion operator used for converting instance of type apple to an instance of type orange (casting)

Comment: @giorashc Oh :) It's been so long I studied the nuances of C++ OOP, I didn't even realize that could be done. Ok, I better be quiet :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a cyclic dependency:

```
class apple
{
public :
   operator orange () const { cout << "operator"; } //depends on orange
                                                    //shouldn't compile
} ;
class orange
{
public :
   orange (apple &x ){cout <<"constructor";} //depends on apple
};
```

I'm surprised you're not getting compiler errors. Anyway, you need to define `orange` before you define `apple`, and you don't need the operator `orange`:

```
class apple;
class orange
{
public :
   orange (apple &x ){cout <<"constructor";}
};
class apple
{
public :
};
```

This should work.

Answer (score 2):

Your `operator orange()` does not return any value. The all point of conversion operators is to convert your instance from type A to type B.

You should create an instance of orange and return it. (Although i don't really see the sense of converting an apple to an orange :))

Comment: In fact, it is undefined behaviour to not return a value from a function with a non-void return type.

Comment: While this is true, it is not the source of the compilation error.

Comment: error: expected type-specifier before ‘orange’ at line 4, even if we define orange before using it then also compiler error comes

Comment: Did you follow Luchian Grigore answer ?